# Postgre SQL переменные 8.4 в запросе

Tags: sql, postgresql

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли в Postgre SQL 8.4 использовать переменные в самих запросах (не в функциях)?
порывшись в инете, я так понял что их нет((

поэтому решил схитрить и использовать временную таблицу, чтобы из нее брать нужные параметры

К примеру:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tempp ON COMMIT DROP
AS
SELECT  'test.ss' AS imptable, --Таблица
    'company_id'  AS column1   --столбец ;

SELECT * FROM  (SELECT imptable FROM tempp) a
where (SELECT column1 FROM tempp) >1;
```

Думал что это сработает, и он будет смотреть в test.ss, но нет:

```
SELECT * FROM  (SELECT imptable FROM tempp)
```

делает выбор не из `test.ss` а из `tempp`, ибо по факту он видит мой подзапрос как таблицу, а не как слово, которое я хочу подставить в скрипт

я хочу чтобы получился результат как если бы я написал

```
SELECT * FROM  test.ss
```

Подскажите как быть, если ли нормальные переменные, без использования функций? Если нет, то как можно еще в запросах использовать что то вроде переменных, изменять что то в одном месте, чтобы не править весь запрос

Comment: А что не так с [common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)?

Comment: используя WITH получаю тот же результат, я хочу подставить название таблицы в скрипте, и использую подзапрос ко времянке, где это название прописано, но он воспринимает мой подзапрос с названием, как таблицу, а не как слово, которое я бы хотел использовать

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример данных, ожидаемый и реальный результаты.

Comment: Поправил описание, максимально все разжевав

Comment: М-м. Вы храните во временной таблице **идентификаторы**, которые хотите использовать при составлении конечного запроса, не зная их заранее. Это странное желание в целом и обычно решаемое на уровне клиента, но теперь хотя бы понятно, в чём суть. И почему не подходят CTE.

Comment: Похоже, что [действительно нельзя](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13289304/2076787).

Comment: Нельзя ни в 8.4 ни в текущей, данная задача вообще выходит за рамки SQL и обычно реальзуется на клиенте. Если пользуетесь PgAdmin, но в нем имеется pgScript. Также, можете использовать для запуска динамически составляемых SQL запросов хранимые процедуры. Вариант не очень, ибо под каждую задачу хранимку в базе хранить, но ведь и хранимки могут быть временными...

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE "STA_User" b
SET "ID" = a."ID", "Username"=a."Username"
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM dblink('port=5432 dbname=Bekap user=postgres  password=123456'
               , 'SELECT "ID", "Username" FROM public."STA_User"')
               AS t("ID" INTEGER, "Username" TEXT)
      )a
WHERE b."ID" = a."ID";
-- Обновить таблицу с такими же ID как у исходной
```

'a' и 'b' преремнные